# Get variable product attributes in WooCommerce

Tags: php, woocommerce, product-variations

I am trying to get a list of attributes for a product using this code

```
<?php global $product;
$boardsizes = array_shift( wc_get_product_terms( $product->id, 'pa_board-size', array( 'fields' => 'names' ) ) );
foreach( (array) $boardsizes as $boardsize) {
echo $boardsize;
}
```

But I am just getting the first value. For example, the product has an attribute called Board Size and the product has three sizes: 10.2ft, 11.2ft, and 12.2ft. I am just getting one value returned is the first one 10.2ft). I need to show all the three values.

Comment: Please share a result of `Print_r($boardsizes);`, then we can understand better to help

Answer (score 0):

Just removed

```
array_shift
```

and it worked !

```
<?php global $product;
$boardsizes = wc_get_product_terms( $product->id, 'pa_board-size', array( 'fields' => 'names' ) );
foreach( (array) $boardsizes as $boardsize) {
echo $boardsize;
}
```